# ¿Por qué después de instalar un plugin/extensión, no hace nada?

Tags: vscode, extensiones

Ya reinstalé y nada.
Ya instalé otro similar, nada.
Reinicié VS Code, nada.

**Por ejemplo tengo Bracket Pair Colorization Toggler, no colorea las llaves.
Tengo Error Lens, no me identifica los errores**

Answer (score 0):

En VSC ve a: File -> Preferences -> Settings

En la barra de busqueda escribe: settings.json (aparece en pequeño y es de color azul).

Una vez dentro, te aparece un .json y le pegas esto:

```
"editor.guides.bracketPairs": true,
   "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "editorBracketHighlight.foreground1": "#B48EAD",
        "editorBracketHighlight.foreground2": "#A3BE8C",
        "editorBracketHighlight.foreground3": "#EBCB8B",
        "editorBracketHighlight.foreground4": "#D08770",
        "editorBracketHighlight.foreground5": "#BF616A",
        "editorBracketHighlight.foreground6": "#abb2c0",
        "editorBracketHighlight.unexpectedBracket.foreground": "#db6165"
    },
```

Es mi configuracion. No necesitas ninguna extension de bracket-pair-colorization.

Ahi veras tus configuraciones de todo (tamaño de letra de VSC, tipo de letra, colores de los parentesis, tema...)

Si tienes algun problema con el error-lens u otra extension, recuerda siempre leer el settings.json. Ahi se guardan las configuraciones.